# Group a list of Scala Ints into different intervals?

Tags: scala, collections, grouping

I wasn't sure if `groupBy`, `takeWhile`, or `grouped` would achieve what I wanted to do. I need to develop a function that automatically groups a list of numbers according to the interval I want to specify. The use case is taking a list of ages and sorting them into dynamic age categories (like 1-5, 5-10, etc.). It would need to be dynamic since the user may want to change the intervals.

For example, I have the list of numbers: `List(103, 206, 101, 111, 211, 234, 242, 99)`

I can interval by `10`, or by `100`. Then the result of an input of `100` would be: `List(List(99),List(101,103,111),List(206,211,234,242))`.

I searched Google and SO for the last hour but couldn't find anything. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want `groupBy`:

```
val xs = List(103, 206, 101, 111, 211, 234, 242, 99)

xs.groupBy(_ / 100)
// Map(0 -> List(99), 1 -> List(103, 101, 111), ...)
```

`grouped` just creates subsequent clumps of a given size, not looking at the actual elements. `takeWhile` just takes the leading elements as long as a predicate holds.

---

You can use the `withDefaultValue` method on the resulting map to make it appear as an indexed sequence, where some entries are empty:

```
val ys = xs.groupBy(_ / 100) withDefaultValue Nil
ys(0)  // List(99)
ys(4)  // List() !
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that generates the ranges and filters for values within them. I think the `l.groupBy(_ / 100).values` is preferable though.

```
val interval = 100

//This gives List(Vector(0, 100), Vector(100, 200), Vector(200, 300))
val intervals = 0 until l.max + interval by interval sliding(2) 


for(interval <- intervals; 
      within <- List(l.filter(x => x > interval(0) && x <= interval(1)))
   ) yield within
```

With `val l = List(103, 206, 101, 111, 211, 234, 242, 99)` this gives:

```
List[List[Int]] = List(List(99), List(103, 101, 111), List(206, 211, 234, 242))
```